# Baked normal map freaking out. Normal node with it as input is Black

Tags: texture-baking, normal-map

I did a retopo of my sculpt and now wanted to bake a normal map using Blenders bake feature.
I created a cage mesh by scaling the retopo up along its normals and then fixing some issues of overlapping topology in sculped mode. In the viewport is the result of a bake with these exact same settings, if I preview the normal map node everything is black. Only the Lowpoly and Cage meshes are UV unwrapped using smart uv project. Could anybody help me out here, I already tried backing with different combinations of Cage extrusions ( with the Cage option of) and Max Ray Distances but nothing seems to work. What am I missing?
[image]

Thanks for your help

Comment: hello, please share your file (with the high poly and the low poly): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Excuse me for using Google Drive but Blend-Exchange nor pasteall did due to the file size not work. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q55h3dp98P4wMM7hZIFLeXvc6R7_xZZ5/view?usp=sharing

Comment: that's weird it seems to work fine here: https://www.zupimages.net/up/21/40/zlwy.jpg ... have you selected the high poly, shift selected the low poly, then Bake?

Comment: also maybe try with another Blender version

Comment: shouldnt it be the other way around First electing the lowpoly and then shift selecting the highpoly, because wen I do it as you mentioned it complains about missing uvs

Comment: Or is it a problem with me using aces? I always set the color mode to Utility Raw

Comment: What version did you use

Comment: I've used the last version, I'm not sure about what you mean with the color mode, do you mean the Color Management setup? It should not change anything... For the selection order, you need to first select the high poly, then shift select the low poly

Comment: Yes, I am using the ACES colour management suit but disabling it did not seem to have helped. I tried it with the 3.0.0 Alpha but there it crashes.

Comment: Thanks for helping solved it see awnser

Comment: ok that's weird because I didn't change your settings...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved by Backing in a new blend file, I suspect that I somehow messed up the render settings